# CSS for pop-up picture and hovering

Tags: html, css, hover, thumbnails, blogger

I currently have CSS code with HTML written such that when you hover over one of the thumbnail images a larger picture pops up above the thumb-nailed images. I currently have two problems:

1.) How can I have the white space above the thumbnails default to the first thumbnail's picture

2.) How can I get the pictures to "stay up" after they have been hovered on such that they will only go away unless another thumbnail is hovered on. Even if the mouse enters white space the last hovered image should still be displayed.

My website can be found here with the image displayer at the top [www.ignitionspeed.com](http://www.ignitionspeed.com)
Also a good example of what I am looking for if it is unclear can be found here [autoblog.com](http://www.autoblog.com)

Here is the CSS I am using for this

```
<style type="text/css">

.thumbnail{
z-index: 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
background-color: transparent;
z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
position: absolute;
display: block; 
left: -1000px;
visibility: hidden;
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
border-width: 0;
padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
visibility: visible;
top: 10px;
left: 13px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
overflow:hidden;
}

</style>
```

And here is the HTML

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.ignitionspeed.com/2012/09/lexus-lf-cc-concept.html"><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/25rBVR.jpg" width="117px" height="72px" border="0" /><span><img  src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/25rBVR.jpg" /><br /></span></a>

<a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.ignitionspeed.com/2012/09/2009-bmw-m3-review-test-drive.html" ><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/IGoDa8.jpg" width="117px" height="72px" border="0" /><span><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/IGoDa8.jpg" /><br /></span></a>

<a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.ignitionspeed.com/2012/09/2013-audi-s6-giant-leap-in-performance.html"><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/aSwPv9.jpg" width="117px" height="72px" border="0" /><span><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/aSwPv9.jpg" /><br /></span></a>

<a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.ignitionspeed.com/2012/09/2012-lexus-lfa.html"><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/Gu1Pey.jpg" width="117px" height="72px" border="0" /><span><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/Gu1Pey.jpg" /><br /></span></a>

<a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.ignitionspeed.com/2012/08/acura-nsx-future-is-already-here.html"><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/VJo9IP.jpg" width="117px" height="72px" border="0" /><span><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/VJo9IP.jpg" /><br /></span></a>

<a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.ignitionspeed.com/2012/09/2012-jaguar-xkr-s.html"><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/REiZ6c.jpg" width="117px" height="72px" border="0" /><span><img src="http://i.tinyuploads.com/REiZ6c.jpg" /><br /></span></a>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: you need to use javascript. create a hover event that defaults the first image, when thumbnail is out of focus.

Comment: There are some demos by Eric Meyer that cover a similar task by creating a menu with pure CSS popups below: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/popups/demo.html and http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/popups/demo2.html (with images).

Comment: are you comfort if the solution uses java-script/jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for [pure CSS](http://cssdemos.tupence.co.uk/image-popup.htm) and if you want to use jQuery use [this](http://css-tricks.com/a-really-nice-way-to-handle-popup-information/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't if you are familiar with Javascript and jQuery. But you have to use Javascript to achieve your desired effect.

The most simple way to achieve it is by adding a class on your elements when you hover on them using jQuery.

```
$('.thumbnail').mouseover(function() {
    //Removing any active hover class
    $('.thumbnail').removeClass('hover');
    //Add class for the thumbnail that was just hovered
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

Then, in your CSS, just modify two of your selectors:

```
.thumbnail:hover, .thumbnail.hover {}
.thumbnail:hover span, .thumbnail.hover span {}
```

Comment: "you have to use Javascript" I don't think so; it's just a little bit more complicated when doing it in pure CSS; I'd like to downvote your answer for that sentence alone – but on the other hand it's a working solution you've posted here…

Comment: The last hovered image has to stay visible when no thumbnail is hovered and I can't think of a way to do it with pure CSS.